# Grav/Twig get title of twig expression

Tags: twig, grav

I want to get the title of a linked page, which is linked by a twig expression.

```
        <a href="{{ header.home.linkOne }}">#TitleHere</a>
```

I tried to get the title with *page.find* but this doesn't work at all.
I don’t want to create a backend field to type in the title manually.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using the twig `find()` command. I think your problem is that you're trying to find based on the title, and you need to use the path. Luckily Grav gives us the `home_url` variable which makes this rather simple.

```php
{% set homepage = page.find(home_url) %}
<a href="{{ home_url }}">{{ homepage.title }}</a>
```

I set homepage up as a variable in case you wanted to use it again on the same page. There's no reason to run multiple `find()`'s if you don't need to. If you aren't going to use it again, you can reduce this to a one liner by removing the first line and replacing `homepage.title` with `page.find(home_url).title`.

Comment: Thanks mate. Solved this.